# Getting called function from LLVM's machine instruction

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Is there a way to get the called function from a machine instruction?

Right now I'm identifying if the machine instruction is a function call or not as below:

```cpp
for (MachineBasicBlock &MBB : MF) {
  for (MachineInstr &MI : MBB) {
    if (MI.getDesc().isCall()) {
      // Function call
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to follow [this](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-July/088100.html), but I'm getting `isSymbol()` as `false` in all cases.

I'm interested only in direct calls (function pointers are ignored).

Comment: I'm not familiar with this part of LLVM but shouldn't `isCall` be called on MI directly? Have you also tried `isGlobal()` on the operands?

Comment: Not sure if it is correct or universal way but I get the callee name in the following way: `MI.getOperand(0).getGlobal()->getName().str()`. Also you should check that opernad `isGlobal()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to directly cast the first operand:

```cpp
if(MI.getOperand(0).getType() == llvm::MachineOperand::MO_GlobalAddress) {
  const GlobalValue *GV = MI.getOperand(0).getGlobal();
  const Function *Callee = dyn_cast<Function>(GV);
  
  assert(Callee != nullptr && "Unexpected type of global value");
}
```